# Is there a site for career related question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I relatively often see general career advice questions like this one: [New Data Science supervisor](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/126285/new-data-science-supervisor)

I have seen this post on meta: [Is a question about future career paths appropriate?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/is-a-question-about-future-career-paths-appropriate) that argues why these questions do not fit this site.

This question is not there to rekindle the debate, so let's assume that career questions do not belong on Data Science Stack Exchange. Are there other sites on Stack Exchange where these would belong?

Answer (score 3):

[Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) or [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com) might fit the bill based on the situation.

However, generally, the stackexchange sites are not meant for open-ended questions with opinion-based answers (a career question is very likely to be that). Hence you're better off using other sites for them (or better yet, talk to irl people with credentials).